# illegal start of term

Tags: prolog

GNU Emacs 23.2.1 
    prolog-mode-version is a variable defined in `prolog.el'. Its value is "1.22"

I have consulted the following file:

```
body(mercury, 36, small, none, none).
body(venus, 67, small, atmosphere, none).
body(earth, 93, small, atmosphere, none).
body(moon, 93, small, none, none).
body(mars, 141, small, atmosphere, none).
body(jupiter, 489, large, atmosphere, rings).
```

However, when I do the following:

```
body(Body, Miles, _, _, _,) , Miles > 100.
```

I get the following error, it seems perfectly legal to me:

```
?- body(Body, Miles, _, _, _,) , Miles > 100.
ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal start of term
ERROR: body(Body, Miles, _, _, _,
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: ) , Miles > 100 . 
?-
```

Can anyone explain I am going wrong?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your query.
It should be

```
body(Body, Miles, _, _, _), Miles > 100.
```